# If it is known that external magnetic field is zero everywhere so what you can conclude about electric field is it also zero

Tags: electromagnetism

A charged particle passing through a region of space has a velocity whose magnitude and direction remains constant. If it is known that external magnetic field is zero everywhere so what you can conclude about electric field is it also zero.
(b)
if it is known that external electric field is so can you say that external magnetic field is also zero?

I am confused as I am not getting right answer.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Given that the particle's velocity is constant, the Lorentz force $\vec{F} = q \vec{E} + q \vec{v} \times \vec{B}$ working on it must vanish.

Therefore if $\vec{B} = \vec{0}$ we must have $\vec{E} = \vec{0}$. If  $\vec{E} = \vec{0}$ we must have $\vec{v} \times \vec{B}= \vec{0}$ which means that $\vec{B}$ must be zero or parallel or anti parallel to the velocity $\vec{v}$.